# Displaying multiple search queries

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn React and want to make a simple Stock App as my personal project.

I've found [free stock api](https://iexcloud.io/). Not sure if correctly but I've managed to display search query result in a separate card. My goal is  to display all search queries in their separate cards but the problem is that each search query replaces already existing card, thus not adding another one. Can somebody point to me where the problem lays in my code? I would really appreciate:

```
 function Dashboard() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    const url = `${iex.base_url}/stock/${input}/quote?token=${iex.api_token}`;
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!input) {
      return alert('Please enter stock ticker');
    }

    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      setResult(data);
      console.log(data);
      setInput('');
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      alert('Unable to find stock price, please check ticker name');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='dashboard-wrapper'>
      <h1 className='dashboard-wrapper__title'>Stock App</h1>
      <form className='dashboard-wrapper__form'>
        <InputField
          placeholder='Search for symbols or companies'
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit} />
      </form>
      <div className='search-results-wrapper'>
        {isLoading ? null : (
          <StockCard
            companyName={result.companyName}
            stockPrice={result.latestPrice.toFixed(2)}
            symbol={result.symbol}
            priceChangeCurrency={result.change.toFixed(2)}
            priceChangePercentage={(result.changePercent * 100).toFixed(2)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default Dashboard;

**UPDATE**
So I've managed to solve my petty problem by using @miraj suggestion with spread operator and .map.

This is correctly working code (thus I'm not sure if it's properly written):

```
function Dashboard() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    const url = `${iex.base_url}/stock/${input}/quote?token=${iex.api_token}`;
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!input) {
      return alert('Please enter stock ticker');
    }

    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      setResult(result => [...result, data]); // This is the part which solved the issue
      console.log(data);
      setInput('');
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      alert('Unable to find stock price, please check ticker name');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='dashboard-wrapper'>
      <h1 className='dashboard-wrapper__title'>Stock App</h1>
      <form className='dashboard-wrapper__form'>
        <InputField
          placeholder='Search for symbols or companies'
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit} />
      </form>
      <div className='search-results-wrapper'>
        {isLoading
          ? null
          : result.map((stock) => (
              <li>
                <ul>
                  <StockCard
                    key={stock.symbol}
                    companyName={stock.companyName}
                    stockPrice={stock.latestPrice.toFixed(2)}
                    symbol={stock.symbol}
                    priceChangeCurrency={stock.change.toFixed(2)}
                    priceChangePercentage={(stock.changePercent * 100).toFixed(
                      2
                    )}
                  />
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: `setResult(data)` will replace your state with new response object. are you facing this problem? and you also need to use `.map` on your component to render each card

Comment: How do I add new response object to my initial state instead of replacing it?

Comment: you can use spread operator inside the `setState()` method to get the old copy of your state and add new data after it. before that you need to initiate the response object in the state

Comment: I've tried to add in try block : setResult(result => [...result, data]) and then cosole.log(result) - I get empty array

Comment: this is happenning bcz they are running asynchronously. before the `setResult()` is finished `console.log(result)` run with the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are not mapping `<StockCard/>` component, you are rendering it just one time. You should map it and depends on your api data length, it will render each information on different StockCard

Comment: If I try to map it, I get error "result.map is not a function". It console logs it' type as object, which I also do not understand why it is an object when initial state is set as empty array.

Comment: Could you try result.data.map, also when you do console.log(data) do you see all correct Api informations ?

Comment: So I've tried to map component as you've suggested by using result.data.map and I get error "cannot read property "map" of undefined". console.log(data) shows me correct API info, while console.log(result.data) shows undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
setState(result => [
  ...result,
  data
])
```

and

```
{isLoading
  ? null
  : result?.map((stock) => (
              <li>
                <ul>
                  <StockCard />
}
```

Comment: `<li>` should be the child element of `<ul>`. `?.` aka optional chainning operator will return **null** instead of **undefined** which will prevent some error